# Let me alone. Leave go of me

Tags: phrase-meaning

Let me alone.
Why is it let me alone and not leave me alone?

Leave go of me.
Why is it leave go of me and not let go of me?

Comment: Either verb can be used in either context.

Comment: This might be a US/UK split.  "*Leave* go of me" sounds very odd in the US.

Comment: To this Brit, they sound *entirely* the wrong way round. Leave me alone & Let go of me.

Comment: Kate Bunting why so?

Comment: Phrases like this are idiomatic - they have a 'normal' form, whether another is technically equivalent or not, the common-usage version is the one people are drawn to. The other just sounds 'odd'.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way around.

You should say "Leave me alone".  It is "leave" because you are asking the other person to depart from you. Leave means "depart".

You should say "Let me go".  It is "let" because you are asking permission to go.  "Let" is the verb used to ask for permission:  "Let her sing"= "Give her permission to sing".